# Dispose not working, many dead connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, dispose

I'm getting strange things since updated to EF6,no sure this is related or not, but used to be good

I'm doing a set of work, then save it to DB , then do another ,  save another.

after a while,i check SQL server by  `sp_who2` ,  i found many dead connections from my computer.

Job is huge then there goes to  700 connections,
I have to kill them all manually in cycle.

program like:

```
while (jobDone == false)
{
     var returnData=doOneSetJob();
     myEntity dbconn= new myEntity;

     foreach( var one in retrunData) 
     {

        dbconn.targetTable.add(one );
        try
        {  
            dbconn.savechange();
            /// even i put a dispose() here , still lots of dead connections
        }
        catch
        {
           console.writeline("DB Insertion Fail.");
           dbconn.dispose();
           dbconn= new myEntity();
         }
     }

     dbconn.dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider refactoring your code so that your connection is cleaned up after your job is complete.  For example:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
        while (!jobDone)
        {
            // Execute job and get data
            var returnData = doOneSetJob();

            // Process job results
            foreach (var one in returnData)
            {
                try
                {
                    context.TargetTable.Add(one);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log the error
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The `using` statement will guarantee that your context is cleaned up properly, even if an error occurs while you are looping through the results.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use a `using` statement. Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

So, your code would look better like this:

```
using(var dbconn = new DbContext())
{
    while (!jobDone)
    {
        foreach(var one in retrunData)
        {
            try
            {
                targetTable row = new TargetTable();
                dbconn.TargetTable.add(row);

                dbconn.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DB Insertion Fail.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, even if your code fails at some point, the `Context`, resources and connections will be properly disposed.

Comment: i think it should be "var dbconn = new DbContext()" instead of db